# How to add a 'selected' in a select dropdown wp/php

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, select

I have a problem which I'm not sure how to approach, I have a WP plugin which has a form, in the form I have a  with result that could have varied amount of data (depending on what the user submits).

How can I add 'selected' to the selected item so when the user returns he can edit/view the item he selected?

```
 <select name="supplier">
    <option value="Supplier 1">Supplier 1</option>
    <option value="Supplier 2">Supplier 2</option>
    <option value="Supplier 3">Supplier 3</option>
    <option value="Supplier 4">Supplier 4</option>
</select>
```

A loop comes to mind, shall I assign a number to each option? There may be 100 suppliers so it would need to count right?

Comment: does this html appears after a form submission?

Comment: 'Should I assign a number..' Of course it should have an ID/index that relates to each supplier in the database.

Comment: What is the plugin name? And when do you want to make it selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a loop like...

```
   $theirChosenSupplier = $supplierVarFromDatabaseOrWherever;
   ?>
    <select name="supplier">  

    foreach($allSuppliers as $individualSupplier) {

     if($individualSupplier == $theirChosenSupplier) {
      $selected = "selected";
     } else {
      $selected = "";
     }

     ?><option value="<?php echo $individualSupplier; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>>
     <?php echo $individualSupplier; ?>
     </option>

     <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

This code isn't tested but should give you an idea. Apologies if I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, I will have a go with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

adding an id is always a good thing. Assuming this is wordpress generated and you don't have a loop already there is always the option of using javascript and maybe an onchange event.

I dont know if the form is submitted first or you do some other stuff but maybe:

```
<select id="foo">
    <option id="provider_1">Provider 1</option>
    <option id="provider_2">Provider 2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {

        var selectedValue = '<?php echo someEscapeFunction($_SESSION['id_provider']); // or _GET, _POST ?>';
        document.getElementById('foo').selectedIndex = document.getElementById(selectedValue).index;
    }
</script>
```